# How to use multiple IF conditional statement using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use an Conditional IF statement using python but not getting the expected Output. Please suggest what can be done next to it.

Input Data :

```
Col1        Col2         Col3    Col4
No Gap     India         80
All Gaps   USA           85
No Gap     India         95
All Gaps   Maxico        90
```

The code i have been trying so far:

```
if df['Col1'] == "No Gaps" and df['Col2'] == "India" and df['Col3'] >=85:
    df['Col4'] = "No"
else:
    df['Col4'] = "Yes"
```

Getting the Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this by using `apply()` method:

```
df['col4']=df.apply(lambda x:'No' if (x['Col1'] == "No Gap") and (x['Col2'] == "India") and (x['Col3'] >=85) else 'yes',1)
```

Comment: Yeah I know @jazrael...I added this in answer **:)**

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Col4'] = np.where((df['Col1'] == "No Gap") & 
                      (df['Col2'] == "India") & 
                      (df['Col3'] >=85), 'No', 'Yes')
print (df)
       Col1    Col2  Col3 Col4
0    No Gap   India    80  Yes
1  All Gaps     USA    85  Yes
2    No Gap   India    95   No
3  All Gaps  Maxico    90  Yes
```